# How to create a raster catalog in global mapper via scripting

Tags: python, global-mapper, raster-catalog

I am a rookie GIS developer and I am having difficulty creating a script for global mapper that would create a raster catalog. Global Mapper provides an example script to perform the task as shown below, but the issue I face is that I need to search for .tif files saved in individual subfolders whereas the GM script targets a specific folder. The script provided is written in CLI, I would prefer to implement in python if possible. Any suggestions?

Sample Script:

```
GLOBAL_MAPPER_SCRIPT VERSION=1.00

// Create the map catalog. Maps should show when they take up at least 10% of display. 

EDIT_MAP_CATALOG FILENAME="C:\TEMP\EXPORT TEST\script_catalog.gmc"      CREATE_IF_EMPTY=YES \ >>ADD_FILE="c:\temp\export test\*.tif" >>ZOOM_DISPLAY="PERCENT,0.10,0" 

// Load the map catalog IMPORT FILENAME="c:\temp\export test\script_catalog.gmc"
```

---*REVISED*---

```
GLOBAL_MAPPER_SCRIPT VERSION=1.00

UNLOAD_ALL 
// Loop over all DEM files in a folder and convert them 
DIR_LOOP_START >DIRECTORY="...\DSM_2m_01\DEM"  
 FILENAME_MASKS="*DSM_2m_01.tif" RECURSE_DIR=YES \

// Create the map catalog. Maps should show when they take up at least 10% of display.
EDIT_MAP_CATALOG FILENAME="b:\DGED\UTM_XX\TEMP\EXPORT_TEST\UTM_XX_new.gmc" CREATE_IF_EMPTY=YES \
   
   ADD_FILE="*DSM_2m_01.tif" \
 
   ZOOM_DISPLAY="PERCENT,0.10,0" \

DIR_LOOP_END \

// Load the map catalog

IMPORT FILENAME="b:\DGED\UTM_XX\TEMP\EXPORT TEST\UTM_45_TEST.gmc"
```

---

I receive the following error:

```
WARNING: Unknown parameter <EDIT_MAP_CATALOG> ignored for DIR_LOOP_START command.
Starting loop over files in directory <...\U_45N320000e6620000n_20km_2000_DSM_2m_01\DEM\> that match '*DSM_2m_01.tif'...

WARNING: Unknown command <ADD_FILE="*DSM_2m_01.tif.tif"> ignored. It looks like a valid parameter though. Did you forget a line continuation character (\) to continue the last command onto the next line?

WARNING: Unknown command <ZOOM_DISPLAY="PERCENT,0.10,0"> ignored. It looks like a valid parameter though. Did you forget a line continuation character (\) to continue the last command onto the next line?

ERROR: Script '...\DGED_Catalogue_Creator.gms' has a DIR_LOOP_START with no matching DIR_LOOP_END.
```

Comment: so you need to scan subfolders in python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687650/python-searching-a-directory-and-subdirectories-for-a-certain-file-type

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I wanted to scan the subfolders yes and catalog all .tif files. As far as python, I wanted to know if GM accepted python scripting or if a GM raster catalog could be produced using python scripts.

Comment: GlobalMapper doesn't allow for any Python scripting, unfortunately.  You could always use Python to generate a GlobalMapper script if you _really_ need to, but that would likely end up being more effort than just figuring out the GM script on its own

Comment: If you format your code using the "code sample" formatting button it will be easier to read than quoting it

Comment: It looks like you may be incorrectly ending lines with the backslash character.  Doing so makes GM treat multiple lines as one (only to make the code easier to read).  But GlobalMapper also treats each line as it's own command, so it thinks `EDIT_MAP_CATALOG` is part of `DIR_LOOP_START`, for example, as indicated by that error

Comment: Thanks @mikewatt I initially tried to use coding tags but it looked so jumbled that I started using the blockquotes. I can try to reformat  it if its not legible. Thanks for the tip about the backslash, I wasn't too sure how that was implemented in the script. I will remove them and see if it runs

Comment: So it looks like I am making progress. I removed some of the carriage returns and received the following output:

'Removed all loaded overlays.
Starting loop over files in directory <...\DSM_2m_01\DEM\> that match '*DSM_2m_01.tif'...
Creating/Editing map catalog...

WARNING: No matches found for *DSM_2m_01.tif

'ERROR: Unable to add any maps to the map catalog.
Loop over files in directory completed.

ERROR: File ...\script_catalog.gmc does not exist.'

is there another command other than ADD_FILE that can search for a portion of the filename instead of the exact path?

Comment: Read through the docs for [`DIR_LOOP_START`](https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-19/cmd/DIR_LOOP_START.htm) to see how to use the files that it's iterating over.  You probably need to use the `%FNAME_W_DIR%` variable within `ADD_FILE` rather than supplying the wildcard again

Comment: @mikewatt The variable %FNAME_W_DIR% did the trick! Thaks for you help!